Uniform distribution over a triangle
Problem
Consider a triangle $T$ with vertices $V_1,V_2,V_3 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and let
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
y&=z+v\\
v&\sim\mathcal{N}(0, R)\\
z&\sim\mathcal{U}(T)
\end{aligned}\end{equation*}
where $z$ and $v$ are independent and $\mathcal{U}(T)$ means that $z$ is uniformly distributed over $T$. My problem consists in finding an expression (not necessarily exact) of the density of $y$.
My approach
Under the current assumptions, the problem consists into compute the convolution
\begin{equation*}
p(y)=\int p_z(z)\,p_v(y-z)\,\mathrm{d}z
\end{equation*}
a simple solution is given by the Monte Carlo method,
\begin{equation*}
p(y)\approx \tilde{p}(y)\triangleq \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N p_v(y - z_i)
\end{equation*}
where $z_i\sim \mathcal{U}(T)$. Now the problem is to sample the triangle $T$. According to this paper, a possible way to do that is to consider the map
\begin{equation}
z(u_1,u_2)=\left(1-\sqrt{u_1}\right)\,V_1+\sqrt{u_1}\left(1-u_2\right)\,V_2+\sqrt{u_1}u_2 V_3
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
in conjunction to $u_1,u_2\sim\mathcal{U}([0,1])$.
Observation
The integral
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 p_v(y-z(u_1,u_2))\,\mathrm{d}u_1\mathrm{d}u_2=
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \mathcal{N}(y-z(u_1,u_2); 0, R)\,\mathrm{d}u_1\mathrm{d}u_2
\end{equation*}
can be expressed in terms of the standard CDF if $z(u_1,u_2)$ is an affine map. While this is not the case for $(1)$, I am curious whether linearization could yield a reasonable result.
Questions

Is possible to derive a closed expression for $p(y)$ ?
Does it make sense to linearize $z(u_1,u_2)$ and then compute the relative integral?


After linearisation, the resulting integral would still have no closed form solution although you could express it in terms of the bivariate normal cdf $\Phi_2$ (which can be efficiently evaluated via numerical integration in e.g. R using mvtnorm::pmvnorm).  But as that solution would only be approximate, you will in generall be better off implementing some form of numerical integration method directly for the problem at hand.  If the triangle is small, $y$ will be approximately bivariate normal with variance matrix equal to $R$ plus the variance matrix of $z$.

If the triangle is large you could perhaps develop an approximation having a form similar to https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/642263/77222 with the triangular density being mollified by $\Phi$ and $\Phi_2$ near the edges and vertices respectively.

What do you mean by small and large? You mean compared with respect to the eigenvalues of $R$?

Yes, relative to the standard devations of $v$.

Is your "triangle" a region in the plane or its boundary or just the vertices you describe??

Interior part and boundary. Sorry for the confusion, I thought it was clear from $(1)$ that I'm not just considering the boundary or just the vertices.

@JarleTufto : I was interested in your previous answer, could you repost it please?

See the R package uniformly.

The density of $\mathbf Y$ at $\mathbf y$ can be seen as the probability that $\mathbf X \sim N(\mathbf y,\mathbf R)$ falls inside the triangle divided by the area $|T|$ of the triangle $T$ since
\begin{align}
f_\mathbf{Y}(\mathbf y)&=\int_T f_\mathbf V(\mathbf y-\mathbf z)f_\mathbf Z(\mathbf z)d\mathbf z
\\&=\frac1{|T|}\int_T \frac1{2\pi|\mathbf R|^{1/2}}e^{-\frac12(\mathbf z-\mathbf y)^T\mathbf R^{-1}(\mathbf z-\mathbf y)}d\mathbf z
\\&=\frac1{|T|}P(\mathbf X\in T).
\end{align}
Numerical computation of the above probability may benefit from making use of the R-package mvtnorm that provides the pmvnorm function for efficiently computing probabilities that singular (see Genz, A. and Bretz, F. (2009), section 5.2) and non-singular multivariate normal random variables falls into rectangular regions.  The  problem can easily be changed into a problem of this type by a suitable transformation mapping the triangle $T$ onto a regular 2-simplex and changing the distribution of $\mathbf X$ accordingly to a singular multivariate normal distribution in $\mathbb R^3$.  The following R code implements this idea.
library(mvtnorm)
dmolunif3 <- function(x, y, v, R=diag(2)) {
  y <- c(x,y)
  y <- y - v[,3]
  v <- v - v[,3]
  A <- solve(v[,1:2])
  A <- rbind(A, c(-1, -1) %*% A)
  sigma <- A %*% R %*% t(A)
  mu <- A %*% y + c(0, 0, 1)
  mu <- as.vector(mu)
  i <- 1:3
  j <- c(2:3,1)
  area <- abs(sum(v[1,i]*v[2,j] - v[1,j]*v[2,i]))
  pmvnorm(lower = rep(0, 3), mean = mu, sigma = sigma)/area
}
dmolunif3 <- Vectorize(dmolunif3, vectorize.args = c("x","y"))
v <- cbind(c(-1,1),c(3,-1),c(0,3))
emdbook::curve3d(dmolunif3(x, y, v = v, R=.1*diag(2)), from=c(-2,-2), to=c(4,4), sys3d = "contour",xlab=expression(y[1]),ylab=expression(y[2]))


Created on 2024-05-09 with reprex v2.1.0

+1 -- but it would help future readers to state explicitly that you consider a "triangle" to be a planar region and not just its boundary.  (An earlier post by the OP concerned the same question but for "segments" instead of a "triangle," suggesting the intended interpretation is the boundary only.)

Yes, I agree, that's not clear from the question.  And I only have a very superficial understanding of the inner workings of pmvnorm so I'm not sure if this is the most efficient method.  But singular distributions is specifically dealt with in Genz & Bretz (2009) so I guess the above approch may be sensible.

The singular case reduces (easily) to a mixture of univariate integrals (or just point values when the support dimension is zero) and therefore the result should be expressible in terms of the error function.
